# Migrate Proxmox VM with VZDump to a system with just QEmu?

Tags: qemu, proxmox, restore

So I have a VZDump of a Proxmox VM image.

What I want to do is import this to QEmu. How would I go about
doing this?

So far the results just show me Proxmox to Proxmox and not Proxmox to QEmu.

Answer (score 1):

Decompress the backup archive. Extract the raw disk image from their [custom vma archive format](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/VMA), [via the tool of the same name](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/vma-archive-restore-outside-of-proxmox.14226/page-2#post-366222). Scratch space about 2x the size of the disk is required.

> 1. On your Proxmox do a backup of your VM
> 2. Decompress the backup to have the .vma
>    2.1. I did with `zstd -d vzdump-qemu-$VMID....vma.zst`
> 3. Extract the vma `vma extract vzdump-qemu-$VMID....vma ./$DESTINATION` it will give you a .raw file (disk image ) and a .conf file (VM
>    Config)
> 4. Fire Up your Virtual Machine Manager than import this disk image (.raw) in a new VM.

The custom nature of this format is why there exists containers that [install just enough Proxmox to use vma](https://github.com/AenonDynamics/vma-backup-extractor). And a [Python implementation](https://github.com/jancc/vma-extractor).